# MySQL Workbench model! remove prefix to all tabels

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to remove table prefix in MySQL workbench model?

For example: I have a complete schema(xxx_table_1, xxx_table_2, xxx_table_N), and want to ask Workbench to remove prefix xxx_ to each table inside this schema, index and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is alter the table and you will be able to rename it, this is assuming the prefixes are not enforced by your database admin.